# Why was Boris Nadezhdin permitted to be a candidate in the Russian presidential election?

Tags: russian-federation, presidential-election, pacifism

Boris Nadezhdin appears to have strong [anti-war views](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/27/world/europe/russia-putin-election-boris-nadezhdin.html?unlocked_article_code=1.Q00.p5VZ.BP1s94QvzLKN&smid=nytcore-android-share), something that is usually seen as punishable in Russia. He was [aiming for the post of president](https://novayagazeta.eu/articles/2024/01/26/pochemu-borisa-nadezhdina-podderzhivaiut-po-vsemu-miru) and looks like collected the required number of signatures.

How is it possible that he was aiming for the post of President, openly [handing out](https://meduza.io/news/2024/01/31/boris-nadezhdin-sdal-v-tsik-podpisi-dlya-vydvizheniya-v-prezidenty) collected 100 000 signatures, rather than sitting in a Siberian prison cell next to Navalny? Why he was permitted to run?

P.S. Boris Nadezhdin was not allowed to the elections claiming that 9147 signatures of the 104 734 provided were invalid but in total about 200 000 were collected ([source](https://meduza.io/news/2024/02/08/tsik-ne-zaregistriroval-borisa-nadezhdina-kandidatom-na-vybory-prezidenta-rf)).

Comment: Is he actually already vetted to be on the ballot?  Or just enough signatures?  Election is not very far away and *official* candidates are sparse.  Maybe one of the ways to ensure that Putin will win will be to delay ballot acceptance till the last minute and force a truncated campaign.

Comment: Related question (in the opposite direction): https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27655/130

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73451/why-do-authoritarian-regimes-bother-keeping-opposition-leaders-alive-in-prison

Comment: "provided" -> "submitted according to the Commision"; "collected" -> "he claims to have collected".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Reportedly, [even Nadezhdin himself doesn't know](https://www.aol.com/don-t-know-why-m-194225150.html?guccounter=1):

> “I don’t know why I’m not arrested.”

The linked article goes on to state,

> The Kremlin says it doesn’t see him as a rival, but the speculation is that they are allowing Nadezhdin to continue, either so that Putin can win against an anti-war candidate, thereby affording himself a mandate to keep the war going, or to provide a release valve for an undercurrent of anti-war sentiment, to prevent it descending into mass protests.

Of course, the given reasons are speculative, but [the BBC backs up the central point](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-68095968) that he's being allowed to compete:

> Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov said on Wednesday that Mr Nadezhdin was not seen as a rival but would be allowed to stand if he met the necessary conditions.

My understanding of "the Kremlin [...] doesn't see him as a rival" is that, essentially, they don't see him as a serious contender and don't think he'll win.

Comment: Keeping up appearances of freedom and democracy is part and parcel of Putin's regime. See also this great book and the many YouTube talks by Peter Pomerantsev: "Nothing Is True and Everything Is Possible: The Surreal Heart of the New Russia": https://www.amazon.com/Nothing-True-Everything-Possible-Surreal/dp/1610394550

Comment: From one of the reviews on Amazon of "Nothing is True...": *"Pomerantsev’s book is about so much more than that though. It’s all about the manipulation of image, news, thoughts. . . In his view, whatever the country thinks it needs, Vladimir Putin wants to be the answer. He wants to be the father-figure. He wants to be the gangster president. You want an opposition party? The Kremlin has one, but it will eventually proven weaker than the President."*

Comment: There's also Stalin's old maxim, paraphrased: "It's not the people who vote that count, it's the people who count the votes." If the Kremlin doesn't want Nadezhdin to win, he won't win, period.

Comment: "the Kremlin [...] doesn't see him as a rival" — that doesn't mean much.  This is what Putin, just like every authoritarian, wants populace to think: there's no oppression, but everybody is united with the President.  Various pacifist freaks (I'm paraphrasing official propaganda) can run, but the won't succeed.  Anyway, "election system" would make sure that Putin wins regardless.  But more likely, he won't be allowed to actually participate in elections on formal grounds, and thus won't spoil the illusion of pro-war unity.

Comment: @KefSchecter - this should be the answer - as those "elections" and "vote counts" are very obviously counterfeit. Take their famous [146%](https://euvsdisinfo.eu/how-to-get-a-146-election-result/) result, or "referendum" to amend the constitution. I am not taking into account him getting rid of any competition here as this is another problem. But even with no competition they need to falsify the ballot to hide all people voting for any freak against pootin.

Comment: @KefSchecter People who are not part of ruling politicum can only win by a landslide. Any narrow victory will of course be taken from them this way or another. I don't see a single reason why Nadezhdin could expect to even get in the second round of election.

Answer (score 20):

The likely explanation that he is a political "background actor" - he is supposed to represent "choice" on the presedential elections, perhaps draw some people to the booths who otherwise will not bother going there.

So it would be possible to create a "picture" of competitive, engaging elections. Kremlin likes creating pictures.

There was a previous iteration a month ago, in the form of [Duntsova](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_(2024)), who will not be in the ballot but did nevertheless draw attention to the election. Now there is Nadezhdin, and if he is deemed to be safe enough he would even appear in actual ballots to lose. If not, he will be kicked off ballot via some legalistic procedure.

And it's kind of obvious why he will lose: Russian elections are extremely non-transparent; then, Russia is a big country with big inertia; and the main one is that he's a nobody. He doesn't represent anybody nor is he a known politician.

It is not known whether Nadezhdin understands that and participates willingly. I cannot claim this is prearranged directly with him, however it is not improbable. Perhaps he hopes to grow his political capital to be used later.

Comment: Yes, if he runs and loses (and really, there's no doubt about him losing, one way or another) then they can say "look, popular mandate for the war!"

Comment: @hobbs, nobody needs a mandate for war.  Also, the absence of anti-war candidates could be interpreted just like that too.

Comment: *'he is supposed to represent "choice" on the presedential elections'* — I doubt that very much.  If it was Kremlin's idea to have a anti-war candidate in these elections (for whatever reason), Duntsova would have been allowed to run.  She is both much better for decorum (in spirit of true democracy, anybody can run for the office), and much less likely to get actual votes in elections (being a relatively young woman, and much less experienced and famous person).

Comment: @NikolajŠ. Nadezhdin is not famous - a low-ish level "system politician" with Yabloko background. Duntsova is a creature of Khodorkovsky, or at least I've heard that (meaning Kremlins likely think that too). Even as she loses she may do stupid things like Tikhanovskaya did. Nadezhdin will not do stupid things.

Comment: @alamar, I never said BN is famous, I only said Duntsova is even less so.  As for stupid things, what can Duntsova do, realistically?  Comparing her to Tikhanovskaya is absurd, Duntsova has no platform, background, respect or authority to do anything except being a protest vote.  She would be much safer choice for a Kremlin-controlled lightning rod.

Comment: @NikolajŠ. At the bare minimum, she could emigrate after the elections and act like a grand duchess in exile. I don't believe Nadezhdin has plans to do so, he would probably play ball and try to capitalize on his new prominence.

Comment: @alamar, *"she could emigrate after the elections and act like a grand duchess in exile"* — so how would it be dangerous, exactly?  Given that she wouldn't have got even 20%, emigrating wouldn't do anything for her.  Tikhanovskaya could claim to be an elected president, Duntsova wouldn't be able to do so.  And leaving the country would only sabotage her political position.

Comment: @NikolajŠ. As you can see, in the end there was no divergence in outcome between Duntsova and Nadezhdin, so perhaps you are right and there is no difference between them in the eyes of Kremlin.

Comment: @alamar, indeed, everything went as predicted (by most).  It was just simpler and tidier for Kremlin to snap his campaign during signature count than to prevent him from running altogether.

Answer (score 5):

Keeps the populace' spirits up, since [надежда](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0&op=translate) (nadezhda) = hope. It might sound like a [Chekhov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Chekhov) novel, if not real (take for example the short story by Chekhov [Смерть чиновника](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_a_Government_Clerk), where the main character is Ivan Chervyakov, and [червяк](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BA&op=translate) (chervyak) = worm).

On a related note, was told by a keen observer that Dmitry Medvedev was chosen to power also because of his resemblance to the last Czar ( see for instance [here](https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/tamech/post178015929/)).

In conclusion, their modus operandi is a bit strange, but relatable. One hopes this candidate won't [make](https://www.newsweek.com/full-list-russians-fall-windows-putin-ukraine-war-1781790) a [splash](https://www.newsweek.com/another-russian-critic-putin-war-died-falling-window-1769721).

There seems to be no reason to worry about this candidate's fate. On this [page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) we read that the above Nadezhdin was an adjoint to [Sergey Kirienko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Kiriyenko). So, we could probably bet that he is a decoy candidate. Whether he is allowed to be on the ballot or not (he is on the [official list](https://2024rus.ru/candidates/nadezhdin-boris-borisovich/)) remains to be seen. Should Putin die sooner or later, he would become a vetted one. Peace for some of the Putin's opponents simply means winning the war faster, or easier, while people in power still get the benefits.  They are debating the means, not the aims. For the vanquished, it means peace of the dead. Read his [official page](https://nadezhdin2024.ru/), one of his slogans is "[Ведущая страна Европы](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B&op=translate)". He conveniently omits  "Rossya", while Putin wouldn't. So much for "nadezhda"...

A recent interview [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amEcNmYzjL4).  Full immunity to Putin and his people, who will go into retirement.  Excerpt - Q: Germany in WW2 occupied countries, some people  were judged and punished, how can you let them off the hook?  A: Yeah, because Germany lost. Rossya will never loose.

Maybe his message is this:  Putin, don't stop the war yet, do what you have to do, then retire, and I come and sue for peace, when the moment is right.  Now that's hope for some.

Answer (score 4):

On 2024-02-05, he was banned.

See e.g. *Financial Times*, "Russia moves to ban presidential candidate from running against Vladimir Putin" ([2024-02-05](https://www.ft.com/content/54f3ffa0-78a0-4977-968a-78fa66a70e6a)).

Comment: Still does not explain why he was permitted to try.

Comment: @Stančikas: You should change your question to, "Why was Boris Nadezhdin permitted to try to be a candidate for about 10 days in the Russian presidential election?"

Comment: In few days. He is still trying to "beat back" the signatures. WTF to fake the signatures when there are twice as much as needed.

Comment: @Stančikas: *"Still does not explain why he was permitted to try"* — because why not?  There's no pretty way to stop a person on that step without breaking decorum.  If BN had been arrested within a few days after unexpected campaign start, that would look quite bad.  Given that there is much easier way to bar him from actually running, why bother?

Answer (score 3):

A viable explanation offers Maxim Katz (Russian politician in exile) in his recent video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XewD7Qifnck - in Russian, human-made EN subtitles)

In essence, the whole reelection machine at some point switched from "do whatever it takes to get Putin overwhelmingly reelected or face a new president unfriendly to all ex-president appointees" to "He will be reelected, this is a stupid formality anyway, do whatever it takes to impress Him because this is what determines your personal success afterwards".

This explains a lot of less than logical decisions - e.g. using signature collection to back Putin's nomination instead of other, less impressive options.

Collecting 100k signatures in order to nominate a president candidate is bound by prohibitively complex and likely to fail procedure (at most 2500 of them are counted from each region, the timeframe is rather restrictive and a great deal of personal data are recorded in the process, the signatures are counted and verified by the president administration, etc, etc...). It is expected that no one would really try.

On the other hand, a pretty much unexpected result of this procedure is a great deal of visibility, should one really tries - e.g. long (spanning few buildings worth of sidewalk), slow moving queues of pretty much determined people and the process going well into the night, for ~2 weeks.

This is nothing like a sane reelection campaign planner would allow in the first place.

And once the big, visible number of people queued on the streets of multiple cities, the system is pretty much unable to react by its usual toolset. In IT security, this is called a "distributed denial of service attack".

The police in a Russia is pretty much able to deal with a big protest (even tens of thousand people) in a single city. Or even in Moscow and St. Petersbourg at once. Or deal with small number of known organizers well before the event materializes.

100 groups of previously unrelated people all over the country is well above their administrative bandwidth. A less clever manager, of course, can always order the police to beat the hell out of these people wherever they are, but the status quo is rather fragile and a forceful attempt is highly likely to backfire.

This is why the signature collection will be allowed to go on and "solutions" will be looked for later.

Comment: From my sources, looks more like he has the signatures already

Comment: Having these signatures gives you nothing as they can get rejected.

Comment: @alamar ... to an extent. Whatever they are trying to picture, Russian authorities cannot do absolutely whatever they feel like. I mean, well, without breaking the whole system.

Comment: @fraxinus This is why they are cautious about the whole framework and would not let a wildcard like Strelkov or Navanly to run. They will have a handful of decoys on every ballot, though.

Comment: This signature-collecting business leaves the authorities all the leverage to disallow a person to be registered.  You have 200k of signatures?  That's cute, but 100,001 of those are incorrectly spelled/unverifiable/bad/unpatriotic.  Better luck next time.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is Boris Nadezhdin permitted to be a candidate in the Russian presidential election?

[He is not](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68237791):

> Russia's election commission has rejected anti-war challenger Boris Nadezhdin as a candidate in next month's presidential vote. [...]
>
> The Central Election Commission said that of the 105,000 signatures submitted by Mr Nadezhdin, more than 9,000 were invalid and they cited a variety of violations.
>
> That left 95,587 names, meaning he was just short of the 100,000 required signatures to register as a candidate, commission member Andrei Shutov said.
>
> "The decision has been made," declared commission chairwoman Ella Pamfilova. "If Nadezhdin wants, he can go to court," Tass news agency quoted her as saying.

I suppose, from the perspective of Putin, the whole exercise was meant to show Nadezhdin can't even muster 100,000 supporters, so he's a negligible thing, and that [also] "democracy works as intended" in Russia. (For a double-entente meaning of "intended", of course. Like the bad guy's grenades [going off](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/oct/05/hand-grenade-explosion-caused-plane-crash-that-killed-wagner-boss-says-putin) on a plane.)

The decision of the Commission appears to have been a wee bit telegraphed by the Kremlin too, [last week](https://www.cnbc.com/2024/02/02/russian-war-critic-boris-nadezhdin-is-an-awkward-challenge-for-putin.html):

> Kremlin Press Secretary Dmitry Peskov told CNBC Thursday [Feb 1] that “we are not inclined to exaggerate the level of support for Mr. Nadezhdin.”

And this appears to bring full circle Nadezhdin's role a as a "whipping boy", if you believe BBC's analysis:

> Boris Nadezhdin is one of the few government critics whose voices have been heard on the ubiquitous talk shows on state-run TV since the invasion on 24 February 2022. He has appeared as a type of anti-war "whipping boy" that other guests would target for criticism.

---

> rather than sitting in a Siberian prison cell next to Navalny?

I didn't exactly follow his each and every speech (understatement), but suppose he might have been careful not to cross the letter of the law, like you know "discrediting the Russian armed forces", although there may be quite a degree of interpretation to that notion, and if Nadezhdin somehow turns out to be more problematic than what can be seen from the above... who knows what might happen.

CNBC's analysis of last week seems to confirm that:

> analysts note that [Nadezhdin] has been careful to stay within recent legislation that has made “discrediting” the armed forces a criminal offense that can lead to imprisonment.

And otherwise also echoes my own opinion thought the voice of some expert as to why Nadezhdin was allowed to collect signatures...

> “Many have speculated, and I think this is true, that the original idea to let him stand as a candidate and collect signatures, and to express the mildly anti war message in his campaign, was to showcase how little support this position enjoys in today’s Russia,” [fellow in the Eurasia Program at the Foreign Policy Research Institute] Tóth-Czifra said.

Comment: I made edit to the question to point out the recent news.

Comment: I don't believe peeking into Putin's head is appropriate. Signature collection happened before and often ended with the same result, which I've pointed out earlier.